# Why 2 interfaces will be created when a WSDL file is imported in the SOAP UI

Tags: soapui

Just wanted know why 2 interfaces will be generated when we create a new SOAP project and import a WSDL file.

Comment: Are you sure that you always get two interfaces?  Could you post a portion or all of your WSDL file?

Comment: 1.http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL     2.http://www.webservicex.net/MortgageIndex.asmx?wsdl                  When imported the above 2 services, each service created 2 interfaces. I'm new to web service testing. Please guide on the same. Thank you.

Comment: I am out of the office until Monday.  Can you please try using both interfaces?  Do they both work?  My guess is that one will not.

Comment: I have tested both the services... and are working fine. The only problem is they importing 2 interfaces. Thank you for the update Tim :)

Comment: One of them is for SOAP version 1.1 and the other is for SOAP version 1.2.